# How to change name of apache tomcat acess url?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I want to change name of Apache tomcat access URL
For example:- **localhost:8080**
I want to change the **localhost:8080** to **myserver.com:8080**
how to do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but about network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you wont to do this on local machine - you should add line to your hosts file.
[how to set hosts](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an virtual host and then change hosts file.
Following link explains it.

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/8485-configuring-apache-and-windows-to-create-a-virtual-host

Comment: Actually should be at least proving the gist of the link you are referring to